# I cant find google play sdk in sdk manager

Tags: android

In my SDK manager I cant find google play services sdk.
there are only 3 options in EXTRA option of sdk manager

1. android support library
2. usb driver
3. Intel emulator accelerator

I tried "Force https://..." option in SDK manager but no effect...
I want to add ad mob ads in my app. Please give me detailed tutorial because I'm new in android development...

Comment: What are the settings and sorting you have for the SDK Manager? Here is mine that has all the Extras: http://i.imgur.com/KtOEDPD.png

Comment: Also check your [Tools > Add-On sites](http://i.imgur.com/YxbcdIa.png)

Comment: all official add-ons are enabled but still facing same problem

Comment: As @MobileDeveloper suggested, what version of the SDK Manager are you running? Perhaps that's your issue. Manager > Tools > About [Mine is 23.0.2](http://i.imgur.com/v6oE5bN.png)

Comment: thanks new version worked.

Comment: Glad it did. You should accept and/or up-vote @MobileDeveloper's answer below to show your appreciation as it was his/her suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to upgrade to latest ADT (version 23) to see Google Play SDK appear as an option.